# how to prompt for number to create folders based on the input?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a BATCH.BAT and when I run it I need to ask my how many folders I want to create:

```
echo How many folders you want? (enter below)
SET /P "ANSWER="
```

then I need to input number (that is not grater then 50 but bigger then 1) and when I hit enter, I need to create folders in this folder `%~dp0..\batch\`. e.g. if I enter number **12** this will be created:

```
%~dp0..\batch\
          |_____ 01
          |
          |_____ 02
          |
          |_____ 03
          |
          |_____ 04
          |
          |_____ 05
          |
          |_____ 06
          |
          |_____ 07
          |
          |_____ 08
          |
          |_____ 09
          |
          |_____ 10
          |
          |_____ 11
          |
          |_____ 12
```

and when folders are created I need to put this in every created folder:

```
IF EXIST "%~dp0..\batch\01\" (
ROBOCOPY "%~dp0..\scripts" "%~dp0..\batch\01" "script.1s" /Z /B
BREAK>"%~dp0..\batch\01\t.ini"
BREAK>"%~dp0..\batch\01\k.txt"
BREAK>"%~dp0..\batch\01\s.txt" )

IF EXIST "%~dp0..\batch\02\" (
ROBOCOPY "%~dp0..\scripts" "%~dp0..\batch\02" "script.1s" /Z /B
BREAK>"%~dp0..\batch\02\t.ini"
BREAK>"%~dp0..\batch\02\k.txt"
BREAK>"%~dp0..\batch\02\s.txt" )

IF EXIST "%~dp0..\batch\03\" (
...
```

**how can I achieve this creating of folders based on input number ??**

**and also how can I avoid to have 49x**  `IF EXIST "%~dp0..\batch\XY\" (` **??**

**EDIT:** here is my atempt:

```
rem @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:0001
echo How many folders you want? (enter below)
SET /P "ANSWER=" 

set ANSWER="%%F"
IF  %ANSWER% LSS 2  GOTO :0001
IF  %ANSWER% GTR 50 GOTO :0001
SET batch="%~dp0..\batch\"
SET max=25
SET min=2

FOR /L %%F IN (1,%max%,%min%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%batch%\0-%%F" ( 
    md "%batch%\0-%%F")
    )
```

Comment: What is your question?????

Comment: @DavidPostill well not sure how much more can I explain what is already stated in the post! I've provided everything I have including my code and also I explained where I am stuck **how can I achieve this creating of folders based on input number ?**. also I am aware that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service... I seek (any) help due to my issue - it doesnt need to be full-script-copy-paste solution/code. I FAIL to understand why this is "too broad" and what are my options now.

Comment: Your options are explained in my first comment. You've only provided 2 lines of code and not made any attempt at the rest of your requirements.

Comment: Hints: [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times, [md](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) - Make Directory - Creates a new folder, [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.

Comment: @DavidPostill edited... (now with my failed atempt)

Comment: [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

Comment: `for /l` only takes three parameters. Please carefully read the documentation for the commands you are using.

Comment: [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.

Comment: Look at the output from your batch file to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: @DavidPostill it tried also with enabledelayedexpansion - let me re-edit it.

Comment: Please carefully read the documentation for the commands you are using. I gave you the link. There is more to using it than just `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. And setting `echo off` is masking any errors in your batch commands.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have read it. I am stuck and I dont know how to proceed to achieve my goal, thats why I ask here in a first place after long-whole-day searching all over SO and SU posts. its not like I am bored and lazy to read! so I do posts and ask for help, waiting that someone will throw me a full bag of gold coins and I just grab them. I highly respect tis comunity, so please be helpfull and dont bully me with that "putting on hold" - I asked my question as I should in a full and clear range. if you dont know the answer (or you are not willing to help out), then let the others to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try has unsolved problems:

- lookup the [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) syntax
- numbers below 10 need a leading zero (solved by adding 100 and taking the last 2 places)
- the variable `%%F` is only valid in the scope of the for command (same line/code block)

The following batch doesn't need delayed expansion due to placing the code in a called subroutine, passing the number as an argument.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\26\SU_1325998.cmd
@Echo off
SET min=2
SET max=50

:0001
Set "ANSWER="
echo How many folders do you want? (enter below)
SET /P "ANSWER=" 
If not defined ANSWER Exit /B
IF %ANSWER% LSS %min% (Echo %ANSWER% is not enaugh min=%min%& GOTO :0001 )
IF %ANSWER% GTR %max% (Echo %ANSWER% is too much   max=%max%& GOTO :0001 )

FOR /L %%F IN (1,1,%ANSWER%) DO Call :Sub %%F
Echo Done
Pause
Goto :Eof

:Sub
Set /A "N=100 + %1"
SET "batch=%~dp0..\batch\%N:~-2%"
IF NOT EXIST "%batch%" md "%batch%" >NUL

:: IMO RoboCopy is overkill here
COPY "%~dp0..\scripts\script.1s" "%batch%" >NUL
for %%A in (t.ini k.txt s.txt) Do if not exist "%batch%\%%A" Break>"%batch%\%%A"
```

---

```
> SU_1325998.cmd
How many folders do you want? (enter below)
1
1 is not enaugh min=2
How many folders do you want? (enter below)
99
99 is too much   max=50
How many folders do you want? (enter below)
3

Done
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

---

```
> tree \ /F
├───batch
│   ├───01
│   │       k.txt
│   │       s.txt
│   │       script.1s
│   │       t.ini
│   │
│   ├───02
│   │       k.txt
│   │       s.txt
│   │       script.1s
│   │       t.ini
│   │
│   └───03
│           k.txt
│           s.txt
│           script.1s
│           t.ini
│
├───scripts
│       script.1s
│
└───test
        SU_1325998.cmd
```

Comment: now I understand (and learned) where I was lacking. danke